# Disabling <a> tag using Ant Design UI Library

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, antd

Is there way to disable a link using antd UI library? According to MDN `disabled` attribute is not supported by `a` tag. Following implementation does work while using React but when using Next.js the link is still clickable.

```
<Tooltip title={tooltip}>
 <a onClick={handleAddToCart} disabled={quantity < 1}>
   <ShoppingCartOutlined className="text-danger" /> <br />
   {quantity < 1 ? 'Out of stock' : 'Add to Cart'}
 </a>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disabled` is indeed not an attribute on links, because a disabled link is just text.

If you still want a disabled link then you have to do 2 separate things

- Remove the `onClick` handler when it is disabled (or have the `handleAddToCart` not do anything)
- Then style your component in a "disabled" way.

Here is an example

```
const isOutOfStock = quantity < 1;

return (
  <Tooltip title={tooltip}>
   <a onClick={isOutOfStock ? null : handleAddToCart} className={isOutOfStock ? 'isDisabled' : ''}>
     <ShoppingCartOutlined className="text-danger" /> <br />
     {isOutOfStock ? 'Out of stock' : 'Add to Cart'}
   </a>
  </Tooltip>
)
```

Then your disabled css can look like this

```
.isDisabled {
  pointer-events: none; // disabled click & hover
  opacity: 0.6; // make it a bit opaque
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, since you're using Ant Design, you can utilize their `Link` component from [Typography](https://ant.design/components/typography/) and add a `disabled` prop. No need to write custom CSS.

```
import { Typography } from 'antd'

<Typography.Link href="https://ant.design" disabled>disabled link<Typography.Link>
```